# Skin node, lip node, how can i have a softer blend at the edge

Tags: node-editor

im very new to blender, followed some tutorial created node for the skin texture and created some node for the lip, any method i can get a kind of mixing these 2 node at the edge between lip and the face skin? Something like weight painting for the materials? I could now only select and assign which part use which materials, thanks for any help

Comment: You should be able to do this with texture painting. If you create a black and white texture, and paint it on so that it is black for only skin, white for lip, and grey for in between, you can then use that texture as the factor for a mix node between the skin and lip nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im very new to blender, im kind of getting what you mean, would you mind to teach me step by step

Comment: Oh i get it now, texture paint instead of weight paint , will try it out, thanks m8